# wmpLib mp3 player playlist with ListBox

Tags: c#, save, load, mp3

Sorry for the english use google translator.
wmpLib mp3 player playlist
I would like to save and load a playlist with a list field.
In the list field you can see the phat and I only want to see the title.
I just started with C# last week.

I've also read that you can do this with two list fields.
Please help !

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamWriter Write;
            SaveFileDialog savePlaylist = new SaveFileDialog();
            savePlaylist.RestoreDirectory = true;
            try
            {

                savePlaylist.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\";
                savePlaylist.Filter = ("XML File|*.xml");
                savePlaylist.ShowDialog();
                Write = new StreamWriter(savePlaylist.FileName);

                for (int I = 0; I < lst.Items.Count; I++)
                {
                    Write.WriteLine(lst.Items[I]);
                }

                string path = @"C:\test.xml";
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path))
                {
                    foreach (var item in lst.Items)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(item);
                    }
                }

                Write.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Playlist saved!");
            }

            catch //(Exception ex)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
```

I've already tried it but no success.

```
 private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Multiselect = true;
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                file = ofd.FileNames;
                for (int x = 0; x < file.Length; x++)
                {
                    lst.Items.Add(file[x]);
                }

                files = ofd.SafeFileNames;
                paths = ofd.FileNames;
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(files[i]);
                }

            }
        }
```

The problem is saving it and loading it into a file